# Failed to load staticwebapp.config.json schema

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app, swa-cli

[image]

when I run the above ADO pipeline task, I get error "**Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json: read ECONNRESET✖ Failed to load staticwebapp.config.json schema. Continuing without validation!
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
/usr/local/bin/az account clear**"

Even after adding the "curl -o dist/staticwebapp.config.schema.json [https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json"](https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json%22) in an attempt to download the schema locally. I still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

The "**`https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json`**" is not a download URL of a json file, instead, it just will return a response body with json content.

To save the response as a json file to the local, you just need to update the command lines like as below.

```bash
# If the 'dist' folder does not exist, create it.
mkdir dist

# Call the URL and save its output to a json file in the 'dist' folder.
curl https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json > dist/staticwebapp.config.schema.json
```

Comment: @RICHARD, Is there any update from you?

Comment: I added that line to the pipeline but it did not work. It looks like swa scheme validation is hard coded check schemaUrl: https://json.schemastore.org/staticwebapp.config.json

Comment: @RICHARD, Can you show the updated details of the task in your pipeline? And the error logs.

Comment: I was able to fix this buy installing a different version of the swa cli. "npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli@1.1.2". For some reason the error "ECONNRESET✖ Failed to load staticwebapp.config.json schema. Continuing without validation! ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1 /usr/local/bin/az account clear" is thrown when you use the latest swa cli.

Comment: @RICHARD, Glad that the issue can be fixed. Maybe, you can post an answer with your solution. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.